# Can I store and read data from “Application” object accessing it from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Can I store something in `HttpContext.Current.Application["MyData"]` accessing that from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you should not do it as this is totally anti MVC practice as views shouldn't be pulling information => views should only use information that is being passed to them in the form of a view model from the controller action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewContext.HttpContext.Application["MyData"]))
</script>
```

Obviously the correct way to achieve this is to define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyDataType MyData { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        MyData = HttpContext.Application["MyData"] as MyDataType;
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally a view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MyData))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

store its value in hidden field and read the hidden field value from javascript or make an Ajax call to read it and return it as json object.

Answer (score 0):

In action:

```
public ActionResult MyData()
{
  ViewBag.MyData = HttpContext.Current.Application["MyData"];
  return View();
}
```

In view:

```
<script>
  var myData = @ViewBag.MyData;
</script>
```

Comment: What if MyData is a complex object? Or if it is a string but containing some dangerous characters?